# How to set "focus" back to contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, windows-8

Working in Windows 8 (IE10 engine). No need for compat with other browsers. I have a contenteditable div with text in it. User clicks another element on the page and I want to paste some HTML into the div where the user's cursor is and then return focus back to the div. I can paste into the div, but then the user can't continue typing and I can't find a way to return the focus. Anyone?

Here's the JavaScript I'm running when the other element is clicked...

```
var sel = document.selection.createRange();
sel.pasteHTML(span.outerHTML);
```

(I did find similar questions but none were applicable)

Answer (score 3):

Just use `elem.focus();`. It should work as normal. To move the cursor to the correct location, use `setSelectionRange`.

Comment: It doesn't work. I think .focus() only works on form controls like input. This is a div.

Comment: @JeremyFoster Which browser are you trying in? It works fine for me in Chrome. [Try this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/HsPtX/)

Comment: See my post. I'm using IE10 (Windows 8). I'll try that demo. Thanks.

Comment: Your demo works fine in my IE10, so I'll look more into my code. Thanks again.

Comment: @digendermahara This is a 5.5 year old answer. You're free to add your own with what works now - I don't plan on retroactively updating all my answers as the browser landscape changes, and I think that's reasonable.